# Option clash for package biblatex

Tags: biblatex, option-clash

I get this error: Option clash for package biblatex and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
%==============================================================================
% Casus onderzoeksproces: Database-performantie
%==============================================================================
% Gebaseerd op LaTeX-sjabloon ‘Stylish Article’ (zie artikeltin.cls)
% Auteur: Jens Buysse, Bert Van Vreckem

% Compileren document:
% 1) latexmk -pdf db-performance
% 2) biber db-performance
% 3) latexmk -pdf db-performance
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{artikeltin}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Metadata over het artikel
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\JournalInfo{HoGent Bedrijf en Organisatie} % Journal information
\Archive{Onderzoekstechnieken 2016 - 2017} % Additional notes (e.g. copyright, DOI, review/research article)

%---------- Titel & auteur ----------------------------------------------------

\PaperTitle{Performantievergelijking van database-systemen}
\PaperType{Casus onderzoeksproces} % Type document

\Authors{Ian Martens\textsuperscript{1}, Voornaam Naam\textsuperscript{2}, Voornaam Naam\textsuperscript{3}, Voornaam Naam\textsuperscript{4}} % Authors
\affiliation{\textbf{Contact:}
  \textsuperscript{1} \href{mailto:ian.martens.y1861@student.hogent.be}{ian.martens.y1861@student.hogent.be};
  \textsuperscript{2} \href{mailto:voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}{voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be};
  \textsuperscript{3} \href{mailto:voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}{voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be};
  \textsuperscript{4} \href{mailto:voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}{voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}}

%---------- Abstract ----------------------------------------------------------

\Abstract{Een database systeem is een belangrijke factor in onze huidige maatschappij. Ze houdt alle data op een gestructureerde manier bij. Andere systemen zijn hier enorm afhankelijk van. De effectiviteit en efficiëntie waarmee de data wordt opgehaald is dus erg belangrijk geworden. We testen in dit onderzoek de performantie van twee database systemen: 'Microsoft SQL Server' en 'MySQL'. Dit doen we a.d.h.v. vooraf opgestelde queries. We testen op uitvoeringstijd, processorbelasting en memory gebruik. Uit de resultaten van het onderzoek blijkt dat MySQL algemeen beter scoort dan SQL Server. Dit verschil is echter verwaarloosbaar. Daaruit kunnen we concluderen dat geen van beide zich echt onderscheid t.o.v. de andere. We kunnen het onderzoek nog uitbreiden door andere database systemen te vergelijken en niet alleen op performantie te testen. Security van een database is ook interessant om eens van naderbij te bekijken. }

%---------- Onderzoeksdomein en sleutelwoorden --------------------------------

\newcommand{\keywordname}{Sleutelwoorden} % Defines the keywords heading name
\Keywords{Database-beheer. Relationele databases --- performantie. MySQL. Microsoft SQL Server.} % Keywords

%---------- Titel, inhoud -----------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%\flushbottom % Makes all text pages the same height
\maketitle % Print the title and abstract box
\tableofcontents % Print the contents section
\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering from the first page

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Hoofdtekst
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Er is al een zekere structuur gegeven hieronder, maar pas dit aan als dat zinvol is (bv. uitvoeren experimenten en analyse resultaten in aparte sectie, enz.).

\section{Inleiding} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering
\label{sec:inleiding}

De wereld functioneert afhankelijk van enorm veel data. Inlogsystemen, stockvooraden, persoonlijke gegevens... Alles wordt wel ergens bijgehouden. Deze data wordt op een database systeem opgeslaan, maar hoe kies je de juiste? Welk systeem heeft de hoogste performantie en is dus het effectiefst/efficiëntst. Om dit te testen voerden we ons eigen onderzoek naar performantie in database systemen. We bekeken eerst enkele andere studies:
\newline
\newline
\textcite{Datastax2018} doet een performance test op NoSQL Database systemen. Cassandra, MongoDB, Couchbase en HBase worden onderworpen aan de test. Apache Cassandra komt er uiteindelijk als de beste database uit.
\newline
\newline
Uit \textcite{H2Database2018} blijkt dat de H2 database in vergelijking met andere engines (Derby, MySQL, PostgreSQL…) de beste zou zijn. We moeten wel opmerken dat dit artikel is gepubliceerd op de H2 website. Er werd voor het onderzoek ook maar 1 pc gebruikt en simpele query’s.
\newline
\newline
In \textcite{Genesky2012} wordt LevelDB vergeleken met MySQL. Beide komen er gelijkaardig uit. LevelDB scoort beter met een hogere troughput en een lage latency. MySQL is wel stabieler over de volledige lijn en scoort even goed bij average latency en update performance testen.
\newline
\newline
Men vergelijkt in \textcite{Lo1998} niet hoe verschillende database engines het tegenover elkaar doen, maar hoe een DBMS zijn performance kan verschillen op verschillende processors.
\newline
\newline
Het artikel \textcite{Nayak2013} maakt de vergelijking tussen relationele SQL databases en NOSQL. Men concludeert dat beide DBMS voordelen en nadelen hebben in performance en dat je beide moet overwegen voor je een keuze maakt.
\newline
\newline
Uit de reading group hebben we geconcludeert dat \textcite{Bassil2012} het meest betrouwbare artikel was. De studie van \textcite{Genesky2012} leek er structureel op. De rest van dit artikel is als volgt gestructureerd:
\begin{itemize}
    \item sectie~\ref{sec:methodologie} beschrijft de methodologie
    \item sectie~\ref{sec:experimenten} beschrijft de resultaten van de experimenten
    \item sectie~\ref{sec:conclusie} beschrijft de conclusie van het onderzoek.
\end{itemize} 

\section{Methodologie}
\label{sec:methodologie}

Beschrijf hier in zoveel mogelijk detail hoe het experiment is opgezet. Het moet voor de lezer mogelijk zijn om aan de hand van de beschrijving het experiment onafhankelijk opnieuw op te zetten en uit te voeren.

\section{Experimenten}
\label{sec:experimenten}

Beschrijf hier hoe de experimenten verlopen zijn en de belangrijkste resultaten. Voeg ook tabel(len) en figuren toe.

Beschrijf zeker ook de uitkomst van de statistische toets: zijn de verschillen in performantie significant?

\section{Conclusie}
\label{sec:conclusie}

Beschrijf hier de conclusie en eventuele bijkomende onderzoeksvragen die in een verder onderzoek kunnen uitgediept worden

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Referentielijst
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\phantomsection
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'm using a template from my school so everything should be right. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: As the only option  you have is for the backend, why don't you use the default backend (`biber`)?

Comment: Dunno, I just use my school's template. I'll try and change it.

Comment: The class is probably already loading biblatex so don't load it yourself

Comment: It works. But I get this error:
Process started: bibtex.exe "dbperf"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: dbperf.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file dbperf.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file dbperf.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file dbperf.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: You need to tell your editor to use `biber` instead of `bibtex` to process the bibliography (and delete your `.aux` files first).

Comment: I deleted the .aux files. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @IanMartens The main part of my comment was about processing with `biber` not `bibtex`. If you're still getting the same error, it's because you're not doing that.

Comment: @AlanMunn Seems Biber is running now: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430191/35864

Comment: NOTE: First, you are saying that [backend=bibtex] and then you say in the comments that you should run biber? Second, latexmk will automatically run either bibtex or biber whichever is needed so there is no need to run anything separately.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here or do we close this? Your suspicions are confirmed by the code shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430191/35864

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted these lines:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

Apparently they were already implemented in the artikeltin file. This seemed to be the problem.