# Error - Data file 'biblio.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'UTF-8'

Tags: biblatex

Hey y'all when trying to add references to my file I get this error:

```
Process started: biber.exe "dbperf"

INFO - This is Biber 2.11
INFO - Logfile is 'dbperf.blg'
INFO - Reading 'dbperf.bcf'
INFO - Found 6 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblio.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Data file 'biblio.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'UTF-8': Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence <92> at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\par-41646d696e\cache-9d6b46fefde4bd584f892f8159e8daefd64788a3\inc\lib/File/Slurper.pm line 63.

INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Here is my main file:

```
%==============================================================================
% Casus onderzoeksproces: Database-performantie
%==============================================================================
% Gebaseerd op LaTeX-sjabloon ‘Stylish Article’ (zie artikeltin.cls)
% Auteur: Jens Buysse, Bert Van Vreckem

% Compileren document:
% 1) latexmk -pdf db-performance
% 2) biber db-performance
% 3) latexmk -pdf db-performance

\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{artikeltin}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Metadata over het artikel
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\JournalInfo{HoGent Bedrijf en Organisatie} % Journal information
\Archive{Onderzoekstechnieken 2016 - 2017} % Additional notes (e.g. copyright, DOI, review/research article)

%---------- Titel & auteur ----------------------------------------------------

\PaperTitle{Performantievergelijking van database-systemen}
\PaperType{Casus onderzoeksproces} % Type document

\Authors{Ian Martens\textsuperscript{1}, Voornaam Naam\textsuperscript{2}, Voornaam Naam\textsuperscript{3}, Voornaam Naam\textsuperscript{4}} % Authors
\affiliation{\textbf{Contact:}
  \textsuperscript{1} \href{mailto:ian.martens.y1861@student.hogent.be}{ian.martens.y1861@student.hogent.be};
  \textsuperscript{2} \href{mailto:voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}{voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be};
  \textsuperscript{3} \href{mailto:voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}{voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be};
  \textsuperscript{4} \href{mailto:voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}{voornaam.naam@student.hogent.be}}

%---------- Abstract ----------------------------------------------------------

\Abstract{Een database systeem is een belangrijke factor in onze huidige maatschappij. Ze houdt alle data op een gestructureerde manier bij. Andere systemen zijn hier enorm afhankelijk van. De effectiviteit en efficiëntie waarmee de data wordt opgehaald is dus erg belangrijk geworden. We testen in dit onderzoek de performantie van twee database systemen: 'Microsoft SQL Server' en 'MySQL'. Dit doen we a.d.h.v. vooraf opgestelde queries. We testen op uitvoeringstijd, processorbelasting en memory gebruik. Uit de resultaten van het onderzoek blijkt dat MySQL algemeen beter scoort dan SQL Server. Dit verschil is echter verwaarloosbaar. Daaruit kunnen we concluderen dat geen van beide zich echt onderscheid t.o.v. de andere. We kunnen het onderzoek nog uitbreiden door andere database systemen te vergelijken en niet alleen op performantie te testen. Security van een database is ook interessant om eens van naderbij te bekijken. }

%---------- Onderzoeksdomein en sleutelwoorden --------------------------------

\newcommand{\keywordname}{Sleutelwoorden} % Defines the keywords heading name
\Keywords{Database-beheer. Relationele databases --- performantie. MySQL. Microsoft SQL Server.} % Keywords

%---------- Titel, inhoud -----------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%\flushbottom % Makes all text pages the same height
\maketitle % Print the title and abstract box
\tableofcontents % Print the contents section
\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering from the first page

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Hoofdtekst
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Er is al een zekere structuur gegeven hieronder, maar pas dit aan als dat zinvol is (bv. uitvoeren experimenten en analyse resultaten in aparte sectie, enz.).

\section{Inleiding} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering
\label{sec:inleiding}

De wereld functioneert afhankelijk van enorm veel data. Inlogsystemen, stockvooraden, persoonlijke gegevens... Alles wordt wel ergens bijgehouden. Deze data wordt op een database systeem opgeslaan, maar hoe kies je de juiste? Welk systeem heeft de hoogste performantie en is dus het effectiefst/efficiëntst. Om dit te testen voerden we ons eigen onderzoek naar performantie in database systemen. We bekeken eerst enkele andere studies:
\newline
\newline
\textcite{Datastax2018} doet een performance test op NoSQL Database systemen. Cassandra, MongoDB, Couchbase en HBase worden onderworpen aan de test. Apache Cassandra komt er uiteindelijk als de beste database uit.
\newline
\newline
Uit \textcite{H2Database2018} blijkt dat de H2 database in vergelijking met andere engines (Derby, MySQL, PostgreSQL…) de beste zou zijn. We moeten wel opmerken dat dit artikel is gepubliceerd op de H2 website. Er werd voor het onderzoek ook maar 1 pc gebruikt en simpele query’s.
\newline
\newline
In \textcite{Genesky2012} wordt LevelDB vergeleken met MySQL. Beide komen er gelijkaardig uit. LevelDB scoort beter met een hogere troughput en een lage latency. MySQL is wel stabieler over de volledige lijn en scoort even goed bij average latency en update performance testen.
\newline
\newline
Men vergelijkt in \textcite{Lo1998} niet hoe verschillende database engines het tegenover elkaar doen, maar hoe een DBMS zijn performance kan verschillen op verschillende processors.
\newline
\newline
Het artikel \textcite{Nayak2013} maakt de vergelijking tussen relationele SQL databases en NOSQL. Men concludeert dat beide DBMS voordelen en nadelen hebben in performance en dat je beide moet overwegen voor je een keuze maakt.
\newline
\newline
Uit de reading group hebben we geconcludeert dat \textcite{Bassil2012} het meest betrouwbare artikel was. De studie van \textcite{Genesky2012} leek er structureel op. De rest van dit artikel is als volgt gestructureerd:
\begin{itemize}
    \item sectie~\ref{sec:methodologie} beschrijft de methodologie
    \item sectie~\ref{sec:experimenten} beschrijft de resultaten van de experimenten
    \item sectie~\ref{sec:conclusie} beschrijft de conclusie van het onderzoek.
\end{itemize} 

\section{Methodologie}
\label{sec:methodologie}

Beschrijf hier in zoveel mogelijk detail hoe het experiment is opgezet. Het moet voor de lezer mogelijk zijn om aan de hand van de beschrijving het experiment onafhankelijk opnieuw op te zetten en uit te voeren.

\section{Experimenten}
\label{sec:experimenten}

Beschrijf hier hoe de experimenten verlopen zijn en de belangrijkste resultaten. Voeg ook tabel(len) en figuren toe.

Beschrijf zeker ook de uitkomst van de statistische toets: zijn de verschillen in performantie significant?

\section{Conclusie}
\label{sec:conclusie}

Beschrijf hier de conclusie en eventuele bijkomende onderzoeksvragen die in een verder onderzoek kunnen uitgediept worden

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Referentielijst
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\phantomsection
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

And here is the artikeltin file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX-sjabloon voor een artikel of kort document
% HoGent Bedrijf en Organisatie, opleiding toegepaste informatica
% Cursussen Onderzoekstechnieken en Bachelorproef
%
% Gebaseerd op ``Stylish Article'' class
% Version 2.1 (1/10/15)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com)
% With extensive modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{artikeltin}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}      % Needed to pick between latex and pdflatex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  FONTS & COLORS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{times}      % Loads the Times-Roman Fonts
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,147,208} % Color of the article title and sections
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  VARIOUS USEFUL PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}                      % hyperlinks
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=black,citecolor=color2,linkcolor=color2,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
right=2cm,%
top=2.25cm,%
bottom=2.25cm,%
headheight=34.9pt,%
a4paper]{geometry}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  FIGURES AND TABLES CAPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
labelsep=period,%
justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  PAGE HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.1cm]{FBO-NL.jpg}}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{\small\sffamily\bfseries\@PaperTitle\  --- \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  SECTION/SUBSECTION/PARAGRAPH SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering#1}}}
  []
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  TABLEOFCONTENTS SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\tocsep}
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  MULTIPLE AUTHOR SET
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcount\@authcnt
\newcount\@tmpcnt\@tmpcnt\z@

\def\@affiliation{%
  \ifnum\@tmpcnt<\@authcnt
   \global\advance\@tmpcnt1
    \raggedright \csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@tmpcnt\endcsname\hfill\\%
   \let\next\@affiliation \vskip1pt
  \else
   \let\next\relax
  \fi
\next}

\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \global\advance\@authcnt1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@authcnt\endcsname
    {#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  LIST CONTROL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  ABSTRACT+AUTHOR FRAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\PaperTitle}[1]{\def\@PaperTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\PaperType}[1]{\def\@PaperType{#1}}
\newcommand{\Archive}[1]{\def\@Archive{#1}}
\newcommand{\Authors}[1]{\def\@Authors{#1}}
\newcommand{\JournalInfo}[1]{\def\@JournalInfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1]{\def\@Abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\def\@Keywords{#1}}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\\}%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{13}{15.6}\selectfont \@PaperType\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi%
}%
}%
\vskip4pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}]%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

This is my biblio.bib I use:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{Bassil2012,
  author    = {Bassil, Youssef},
  title     = {A Comparative Study on the Performance of the Top DBMS Systems},
  journal   = {Journal of Computer Science and Research},
  year      = {2012},
  volume    = {1},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {20--31},
  month     = feb,
  issn      = {2227-328X},
  abstract  = {Database management systems are today’s most reliable mean to organize data into collections that can be searched and
updated. However, many DBMS systems are available on the market each having their pros and cons in terms of reliability,
usability, security, and performance. This paper presents a comparative study on the performance of the top DBMS systems.
They are mainly MS SQL Server 2008, Oracle 11g, IBM DB2, MySQL 5.5, and MS Access 2010. The testing is aimed at
executing different SQL queries with different level of complexities over the different five DBMSs under test. This would pave
the way to build a head-to-head comparative evaluation that shows the average execution time, memory usage, and CPU
utilization of each DBMS after completion of the test.},
  keywords  = {DBMS, Performance Study, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, DB2, Access},
  owner     = {bert},
  timestamp = {2017-01-28},
}

@Electronic{VanVreckem2017,
  author       = {Van Vreckem, Bert},
  title        = {De bachelorproef informatica: een praktische gids},
  year         = {2017},
  url          = {https://github.com/HoGentTIN/bachproef-gids},
  version      = {v0.9.1},
  organization = {Hogeschool Gent},
  urldate      = {2017-02-08},
  owner        = {bert},
  timestamp    = {2017-02-08},
}

@Electronic{Datastax2018,
  author       = {Datastax},
  year         = {2018},
  title        = {Cassandra vs. MongoDB vs. Couchbase vs. HBase},
  organization = {Datastax},
  url          = {https://www.datastax.com/nosql-databases/benchmarks-cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-hbase},
  owner        = {Ian},
  timestamp    = {2018-04-26},
  urldate      = {2018-04-26},
  version      = {v0.9.1},
}

@Electronic{Genesky2012,
  author       = {Eric Genesky},
  year         = {2012},
  title        = {A Performance Comparison of LevelDB and MySQL},
  organization = {Database Zone},
  url          = {https://dzone.com/articles/performance-comparison-leveldb},
  owner        = {Geoffrey},
  timestamp    = {2018-04-26},
  urldate      = {2018-04-26},
  version      = {v0.9.1},
}

@Article{Nayak2013,
  author    = {Nayak, Ameya and Poriya, Anil and Poojary, Dikshay},
  title     = {Type of NOSQL databases and its comparison with relational databases},
  journal   = {International Journal of Applied Information Systems},
  year      = {2013},
  volume    = {5},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {16--19},
  month     = mar,
  issn      = {2249-0868},
  abstract  = {NOSQL databases (commonly interpreted by developers as
„not only SQL databases? and not „no SQL?) is an emerging
alternative to the most widely used relational databases. As
the name suggests, it does not completely replace SQL but
compliments it in such a way that they can co-exist. In this
paper we will be discussing the NOSQL data model, types of
NOSQL data stores, characteristics and features of each data
store, query languages used in NOSQL, advantages and
disadvantages of NOSQ.},
  keywords  = {ACID, BASE properties, CAP theorem, DBaaS, scalability },
  owner     = {Ian},
  timestamp = {2018-04-26},
}

@Electronic{H2Database2018,
  author       = {H2Database},
  year         = {2018},
  title        = {Performance Comparison},
  organization = {H2Database},
  url          = {http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html},
  owner        = {Jentel},
  timestamp    = {2018-04-26},
  urldate      = {2018-04-26},
  version      = {v0.9.1},
}

@Article{Lo1998,
  author    = {Lo, Jack L and Barroso, Luiz Andr{\'e} and Eggers, Susan J and Gharachorloo, Kourosh and Levy, Henry M and Parekh, Sujay S},
  title     = {An analysis of database workload performance on simultaneous multithreaded processors},
  journal   = {IEEE Computer Society},
  year      = {1998},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {39--50},
  month     = apr,
  issn      = {0163-5964},
  abstract  = {Simultaneous multithreading (SMT) is an architectural technique in which the processor issues multiple instructions from multiple threads each cycle. While SMT has been shown to be effective on scientific workloads, its performance on database systems is still an open question. In particular, database systems have poor cache performance, and the addition of multithreading has the potential to exacerbate cache conflicts.This paper examines database performance on SMT processors using traces of the Oracle database management system. Our research makes three contributions. First, it characterizes the memory-system behavior of database systems running on-line transaction processing and decision support system workloads. Our data show that while DBMS workloads have large memory footprints, there is substantial data reuse in a small, cacheable "critical" working set. Second, we show that the additional data cache conflicts caused by simultaneous multithreaded instruction scheduling can be nearly eliminated by the proper choice of software-directed policies for virtual-to-physical page mapping and per-process address offsetting. Our results demonstrate that with the best policy choices, D-cache miss rates on an 8-context SMT are roughly equivalent to those on a single-threaded superscalar. Multithreading also leads to better interthread instruction cache sharing, reducing I-cache miss rates by up to 35%. Third, we show that SMT's latency tolerance is highly effective for database applications. For example, using a memory-intensive OLTP workload, an 8-context SMT processor achieves a 3-fold increase in instruction throughput over a single-threaded superscalar with similar resources.},
  keywords  = {Computer systems organization, General and reference, Information systems, Networks, Architectures, Dependable and fault-tolerant systems and networks, Cross-computing tools and techniques, Data management systems, Network performance evaluation, Parallel architectures, Performance, Database management system engines  },
  owner     = {Jentel},
  timestamp = {2018-04-26},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

These are all templates from my school and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The error message shows that the problem is in your `.bib` file. Check the file encoding (it should be UTF-8) and double check that nothing weird is going on.

Comment: Unrelated to your question and not necessarily relevant for your real document: Don't use `\newline` in text. You can get start a new paragraph by leaving an entire line blank. Other than that you should not manually break lines.

Comment: Note that the class file should be loading the `hyperref` package later (`hyperref` should normally be loaded last). It is also a bit 'meh' that the class hard-codes a `.bib` file. You should try and contact the maintainer of the class about that. Not all classes from `LaTeXTemplates.com` are well known for their exceptional quality, so basing a university class on them is risky if the code is not scrutinised before use.

Comment: @moewe I added the .bib file I use in my question. I don't see an error.

Comment: Indeed the `.bib` file as posted contains only ASCII chars. Can you double check that this is the file that is found by Biber and that it is indeed encoded as UTF-8 on your machine. Does `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bibencoding=ascii}` help?

Comment: I see one problem with your `.bib` file: You need to escape the `%` in the `abstract` of `Lo1998`: It must read `to 35\%.`  instead of `to 35%.`. This should not cause the error you show in your question, but it *will* cause an error later on, so must be resolved.

Comment: Any news here? Could you solve or at least isolate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Got 2 mistakes I had to resolve:

1. Made sure the encoding in the bib file was UTF-8.
2. Changed the 35% to 35\%.

It worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the encoding manually on Debian as follows:

iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 references.bib > references2.bib

Afterwards, I had to delete the file references.bib and rename references2.bib to references.bib again.